# Need a quick way to find an object using two keys

Tags: c++, stl

What is an idiomatic way in C++ to have an object store that can be searched with respect to two keys? Essentially what I would like is to store things of type A in a binary search tree (BST) with the BST constructed using the order relation on A.key. However, each A also has a unique A.otherval and I essentially need to delete keys based on this value.

In C I would typically just have a BST with parent pointers and a hash table based with the other values as a key storing pointers to nodes of the BST. I can delete keys through the hash table by getting the node and calling tree delete on that node.

I'm looking for how to do this correctly using STL containers.

Comment: BST = binary search tree?

Comment: Using STL you can only use two containers in parallel. With boost you would use boost::multi_index container to solve your problem naturally. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: how about keeping two maps, say std::map<first_key_type, value_type> map1, and std::map<second_key_type, first_key_type_as_value> map2. I think that's what @PeterG. meant by keeping two containers in parallel

Comment: @sanjayk79: Store an iterator rather than a key in the second map, to save a second O(N) lookup.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I meant to delete the the entry from the first map it would be something like map1[map2[second_key]].erase(), so it would still be O(logN) not O(N). But, agree with you, keeping iterator is amortized O(1)

Comment: @sanjayk79: Sorry, I meant to say "a second O(logN) lookup", and not to imply that it would be O(N).

Answer (score 1):

If I got the question correctly, all you need is a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) in a map, so

```
std::map<first_key_type, std::map<second_key_type, value_type>> map;
map[key1][key2] = something;
```

Edit:

I assume that all the values that have the same first key are the same, and the second key is only used as an additional search/remove criteria. In that case, to get the value by the first key only you can use something like

```
map.at(key).cbegin()->second;
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but in some other parts of the program it would be much easier to just have one large tree using the first key type, since at that point the other key is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two maps, one to map the key to the instance of `A` (the primary map), and another to map the `otherVal` to the key:

```
typedef ... Key;
typedef ... OtherVal;
struct A { Key key; OtherVal otherVal; ... };

typedef std::map<Key,A> KeyToAMap;
typedef std::map<OtherVal,Key> OtherValToKeyMap;

KeyToAMap keyToAMap;
OtherValToKeyMap otherValToKeyMap;
```

This way you can work with `keyToAMap` without any additional complexity, but when it comes time to delete, you just need an additional lookup.

To ease the usage, I would also recommend writing functions for wrapping insertion and deletion in both maps:

```
void insertNewA(const A& a) {
    keyToAMap.insert(std::make_pair(a.key, a ));
    otherValToKeyMap.insert(std::make_pair(a.otherVal, a.key ));
}

void deleteByOtherVal(const OtherVal& otherVal) {
    OtherValToKeyMap::iterator it1 = otherValToKeyMap.find(otherVal);
    if (it1 == otherValToKeyMap.end()) { /* error */ }
    Key& key = it1->second;
    KeyToAMap::iterator it2 = keyToAMap.find(key);
    if (it2 == keyToAMap.end()) { /* error */ }
    keyToAMap.erase(it2);
    otherValToKeyMap.erase(it1);
}
```

An advantage of this solution is it only requires two maps, as opposed to a multi-level map solution, which requires 1+N maps, where N is the number of entries in the primary map.